# Second Taxicab Number Generator

Tags: f#, number-theory

I am attempting to generate a series of guesses for the second Taxicab number. What I want to do is is call the Attempt function on a series of integers in a finite sequence. I have my two questions about implementation in the comments.
A taxi cab number, in case your wondering, is the least number that satisfied the sum of 2 unique cubes in for n unique sets of 2 unique cubes. Ta(2) is 1729.

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let Attempt (start : int) =
        let stop = start+20
        let integerList = [start..stop]
        let list = List.init 3 (fun x -> integerList.[x])
        //Is there a simple way to make initialize the list with random indices of integerList?
        let Cube x = x*x*x
        let newlist = list |> List.map (fun x -> Cube x)
        let partitionList (x : List<int>) (y : int) = List.sum [x.[y];x.[y+1]]
        let intLIST = [0..2]
        let partitionList' = [for i in intLIST do yield partitionList newlist i]
        let x = Set.ofList partitionList'
        let y = Set.ofList partitionList'
        //I was going to try to use some kind of equality operator to determine whether the two sets were equal, which could tell me whether we had actually found a Taxicab number by the weakened definition.
        System.Console.Write(list)
        System.Console.Write(newlist)
let rnd = System.Random()
//My primary question is how can I convert a random to an integer to use in start for the function Attempt?
System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
printfn("%A") argv
0
```

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what you're asking. Could you [reduce your question to the bare essentials](http://sscce.org), please?

Comment: You don't need to convert random to integer. Using `let rnd = System.Random().Next(9)` will give you pseudo-random number from 0 to 8 for example. See  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx for reference

Comment: This is really 3 different questions.  Its best to ask one per post.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty way to initialize list with random indexes of another list:

```
let randomIndexes count myList =
    let rand = System.Random()
    seq {
        for n = 1 to count do
            yield rand.Next(List.length myList) }
    |> Seq.distinct 
    //|> Seq.sort // if you need them sorted
    |> List.ofSeq

let result = randomIndexes 5 [3;2;4;5]
printfn "%A" result
```